# Differences between Eclipse Indigo and Eclipse 2021

Tags: c++, eclipse, gcc, eclipse-cdt

Since years I use Yagarto with Eclipse CDT Indigo. In a virtual machine on XP. I tried now Eclipse 2021 on Win 10. Copy Yagarto, AT91LIB and the projects. Replaced msys-1.0.dll in Yagarto Tools. Set PATH, so arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe is accesible from everywhere. Set all entries like in Indigo.
Project - Properties - C/C++ Build - Settings - Cross Settings
Project - Properties - C/C++ Build - Settings - Build Steps
....

If I start a Build, the console shows multiple 'rm -rf...', no problems appear in the list.

But it seems the compiler is never called! No .o is build, no output, nothing. The build stops.

There are a few, perhaps subtle, differences between the versions. Did you know the one, you bang your head when finding it?

Many thanks for your help.

BTW: First get this to run, thinking of changing to a different toolchain or whatever later

Comment: Well Indigo is 11 years and 21 releases old compared to Eclipse 2021-12 so there are going to be quite a few changes. But you need to provide more details before we can really help.

Comment: For every file in tjhe project on Indigo there is an output like:

Invoking: Cross GCC Compiler
arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=arm926ej-s -I"c:/arm9_projekte/at91lib" -I"C:/Yagarto_4.7.2/arm-none-eabi/include" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"RSTC/rstc.d" -MT"RSTC/rstc.d" -o "RSTC/rstc.o" "../RSTC/rstc.c"

In 2021 there is just nothing, like the gcc is never called. Even not tried. No 'not found' are so.

Comment: Only this was needed in Indigo:

https://imgur.com/gallery/0M8GVrs